# How to make GMSPlace Codable?

Tags: ios, swift, codable

anyone idea about to make GSMPlace as codable from googleplaces?

what I want is, store GMSPlace data(place and name) into UserDefaults and then retrieve from UserDefaults  and store back to destinationPlace.

```
import Foundation
import RxSwift
import RxCocoa
import GooglePlaces

class SearchViewModel {

    var destinationPlace: BehaviorRelay<GMSPlace?> = BehaviorRelay(value: nil)

    var isValid: Bool {
        if destinationPlace.value != nil {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any of the specifics of `GooglePlaces` or the object type `GMSPlace`.

But in Swift if you want to add something to a class you can create an extension, optionally add protocols to it and add functions. In your case it would look something like this:

```
extension GMSPlace: Codable {

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case propertyName1
        case propertyName2
        ...
    }
    
    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        propertyName1 = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .propertyName1)
        propertyName2 = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .propertyName2)
    }
    
    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(propertyName1, forKey: .propertyName1)
        try container.encode(propertyName2, forKey: .propertyName2)
    }
}
```

You will have to figure out the specifics of what properties you need to include, what types they need to map to etc.

You should also open a ticket for them somewhere to add this to the SDK themselves if its causing an issue for you

Comment: I got this two errors
1. nitializer requirement 'init(from:)' can only be satisfied by a 'required' initializer in the definition of non-final class 'GMSPlace'
2.'let' property 'name' may not be initialized directly; use "self.init(...)" or "self = ..." instead

Comment: when I write required in init method, it says write required in GMSPlace Class ,
can you please tell me where I should write required in GMSPlace

Comment: @Dhiren `required` needs to be added between the public and init so `public required init(from ...)`. the second error is telling you that the property `name` is required to have a value set at the end of the init and you didn't set one. Its telling you to either set one yourself or call an init on the super class in order to complete the rest of the init. It would be worth your time to research what `Codable` is, how it works and why you need it before trying to squeeze it in. Codable is a very important aspect of Swift: https://www.raywenderlich.com/3418439-encoding-and-decoding-in-swift